# Corona facebook.logout() when the Official Facebook app is installed on device

Tags: facebook, lua, facebook-apps, coronasdk

I have a little issue when I want to logout from Facebook and the official Facebook app is installed on device.

After `facebook.logout()` is called then I call the new `facebook.login( appId, fbListener,  {"publish_stream"} )` that doesn't call the app for new user, simple log in with the old username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it is meant to work if the user is logged in to their account on the official FB app, it's supposed to simplify the process, if I recall correctly. (May want to refer to FB docs for more detailed explanation of the process.)