# logout Facebook and clear session in corona

Tags: ios, facebook, session, coronasdk, logout

I have an app which is written by lua using corona SDK. I need to logout a Facebook user and clear sessions in the device. But after I logout the user by using corona API the session or cookie keeps the user logged in!

How can I logout a user completely from Facebook and clear sessions and cookies in Corona?

I have searched a lot but can't found a solution! Maybe another way is to logout the user by using access token of facebook in my device?

Comment: Havent used corona, but can you change the user access token to null anyhow? that might work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120164/corona-facebook-logout-when-the-official-facebook-app-is-installed-on-device

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at this blog where there is an answer for your question

http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/42051-does-facebooklogout-actually-do-anything/

Hope this could help you in some way