# Corona SDK facebook.logout() not working

Tags: facebook, coronasdk

I have the same issue as described here: [Corona facebook.logout() when the Official Facebook app is installed on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120164/corona-facebook-logout-when-the-official-facebook-app-is-installed-on-device)

The answer says that this is by design, but lot's of apps allow you to logout of Facebook and log back in as another user.  Any idea why facebook.logout() doesn't do what the function implies it should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a user of the Facebook native app, I would be highly agitated if another app I ran logged me out.  I've been working with someone in the Corona forums asking the same question (Perhaps it's your post) who's building a Kiosk app, so I can see a need in that circumstance to want this feature.  But given that mobile devices are highly tied to individuals, this is not a behavior that most people would want to see.

The Corona SDK facebook.logout()'s purpose is to disconnect the Corona SDK app from Facebook, cancelling the access Token.  It was never intended to terminate the facebook app's user login.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I'm the same poster, so no need to split answers across threads.  But for future SO readers, my application involves a public kiosk where different users will be sharing photos to their own Facebook walls.  So in normal situations, I agree, logging out is not desirable.  Just this specific case is a multi-user application, so logging out of the native app is what I need.  Thanks to Rob, it's being looked into by the Corona team, so if a solution is reached, I will update this answer.